# Difference between => and -> in Scala

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I'm just going over some Scala tutorials on the Internet and have noticed in some examples the author used both => and -> in a HOF(Higher Order Function).

Example:

```
val vec = Vector("hello", "world").map(s => s -> s.length)
// vec: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(String, Int)] = 
// Vector((hello,5), (world,5))
```

What is the difference between **=>** and **->** in Scala?

Comment: `s` is the received parameter for this lambda (anonymous function). `->` pairs up two values. A quick way to create a 2-tuple.

Comment: It's recommended to first read some basic doc/tutorial (like https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html )

Comment: As already mentioned. `x => y` creates a **function** that takes an argument called `x` and returns the `y` **expression** _(which may use `x`)_. On the other hand `x -> y` creates the **tuple** `(x, y)`. - The first one is base syntax provided by the language itself, whereas the second is just an example of an **extension method** provided by the standard library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032147/solve-a-prediction-based-problem-using-spark-scala-in-eclipse Guys any idea for this. Please provide solution if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**->** it used to associate key with a value  by using implicit conversion for example tuple, map etc.

```
scala> 1 -> 2
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> val map = Map("x" -> 12, "y" -> 212)
```

Its basically just take the item on the left and map it to the item on the right

It converts any type into an instance of "ArrowAssoc" using implicit conversion

```
implicit def any2ArrowAssoc[A](x: A): ArrowAssoc[A] = new ArrowAssoc(x)


class ArrowAssoc[A](x: A) {
    def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(x, y)
}
```

**=>** is a syntax provided by the language itself to create instance of function using call-by-name. 
It passes value name inside the method for example:

```
`def f(x:Int => String) {}` function take argument of type Int and return String
```

You can also pass no argument like below

`() => T`  `means it doesn't take any argument but return type T`.

Answer (score 0):

-> is used for Method provided by implicit conversion & `key->value` creates a tuple (key,value).

=> is used for function types, function literals, and import renaming.